# Repeated measures ANOVA with missing data

Tags: anova, spss, repeated-measures, missing-data

I have a DB with multiple missing values (scale, ordinal and nominal). I used multiple imputation to fill in these missing values.

How can I perform a repeated measures ANOVA on these (5) datasets? Should I pool them first? And how (or can) I run a repeated measures ANOVA straight away with these 5 (MI) datasets?

I work with SPSS

Comment: Please read SPSS Help docs (including Case Studies) about multiple imputation.

Comment: I have, and I have read 

"Analysis of Variance of Multiply Imputed Data by Joost R. van Ginkel and Pieter M. Kroonenberg"

All i can think of is: run RMA on all 5 datasets and get means of the results. Is this the correct way to go?

Comment: I think you have to use split file in SPSS, in SAS  you will use class statment.  And maybe a  mixed model is a better option when you have missing values.